FULLTEXT searching for spaces, full stops
I am experimenting with FULLTEXT searching, using the InnoDB storage engine.  I am upgrading from MYISAM to InnoDB and I have noticed that a lot of queries containing LIKE clauses, which were fast with MYISAM, are much slower using InnoDB.  Removing the LIKE clause and replacing it with FULLTEXT searching is lightning fast in InnoDB, but seems to come with a couple of gotchas which I hadn't thought about.
The FULLTEXT parser works out where words start and end by looking at certain characters including spaces ( ), commas (,) and full stops ('.').  A lot of the rows in my table contain one or more of those characters and it is causing me issues.  Imagine my table contains 5 rows with the string 'test.demo' and my search query 'test.demo' returns results including 'demo', 'string.demo_example' etc. because it searches for 'demo' instead of 'test.demo'.
I know that is the intended behaviour because this is a text search, not a full stop search!  On a practical level, I'd like to to figure out a way to add full stops to the search criteria if possible.  Perhaps it is possible to alter the search criteria somewhere.  Alternatively, I could create a duplicate column of my data for FULLTEXT searching, stripping out spaces, commas, full stops etc.  Then I could strip out these characters from the search string.  I have a working demo of this but it seems a lot of work to go to.

can you please make a dbfidlle with some data , to demonstrate your problem

Fulltext only looks at words, it ignores punctuation. Similar to google searching.

I'm not sure why LIKE searches are slowing down significantly. If you have a pattern beginning with % it should be slow in either engine, since it can't use an index. LIKE can only use an index if there's fixed text at the beginning of the pattern.

You can combine both searching methods, e.g. WHERE MATCH(column) AGAINST ('test demo') AND column LIKE '%test.demo%'

Did you try boolean mode of fulltext search with exact search operator?

@Barmar You were right to question why LIKE searches were slowing down. I found the cause and the issue was due to the use of the REPLACE function in the query when using InnoDB (works fine with MYISAM).
